# How I can divide a newline and two newline in regular expression?

Tags: python, regex, newline

I want to **group** output of regular expression by:

1. newline '\n'
2. two newline '\n\n'

How can I divide into 2 groups in order to use other regex split method?

Find separate newline or two newlines I managed.
For example:

```
Facebook and Google exploited a feature__(\n)__  
intended for “enterprise developers” to__(\n)__  
distribute apps that collect large amounts__(\n)__  
of data on private users, TechCrunch first reported.__(\n\n)__   

Apple’s maneuver has been characterized by some as a chilling demonstration of the company’s power.__(\n)__  
Verge editor-in-chief Nilay Patel suggested in a tweet that it was cause for concern: First, they came for our enterprise certificates, then… well, what, exactly?__(\n\n)__  

Some text so on...
```

I tried this code:

```
def find_newlines(file):
    with open(file, "r") as content:
       text = content.read()
       content = re.split("\n+", text)
    return content
```

The result was:

```
['Apple' , 'Something', 'Enything']
```

I wanted the following output:

```
['Facebook and Google exploited a feature intended for “enterprise developers” to distribute apps that collect large amounts of data on private users, TechCrunch first reported.' __,__ 'Apple’s maneuver has been characterized by some as a chilling demonstration of the company’s power. Verge editor-in-chief Nilay Patel suggested in a tweet that it was cause for concern: First, they came for our enterprise certificates, then… well, what, exactly?']
```

I want to get 1 group of newline
and 2 group of two newlines.

Comment: can you show how the output looks like.

Comment: could you clarify what you mean by group? do you want two lists, one with all the lines that are divided by at least one \n and another list with lines that are divided by two \n characters? The result you post also doesn't match your example, with your current code your result should be a list with seven elements: ['Facebook..', 'intended...', 'distributed...', 'of data...', 'Apple's...', 'Verge...', Some text...']

Comment: For that text, would do you want `content` to look like? You can use the [edit] button to make improvements to your question.

Comment: The output look like this "FOCUS\nTRANSFORM\nDELIVER\n"

Comment: And that is the output you want?

Comment: @Freya W by group I mean  regular expression with two parenthesis (\n ) (\n\n ) and we take each one by group(1), group(2). What about post result you totally right. Actually I tried  \n+ and I got   ['Facebook..', 'intended...', 'distributed...', 'of data...', 'Apple's...', 'Verge...', Some text...'].

Comment: Martin Evans thank you for suggestion. I will edit and add the how output should look like

Comment: Do you mean something like this? `content = [' '.join(block.split('\n')) for block in text.split('\n\n')]`  (not using regex)

Comment: I thought only about regex. I will try this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be trying to group your text into two (or more) blocks delimited by double newlines. As such one approach is to first split the text on `\n\n`. This will result in `blocks` which still contain single newlines. Each block could then have any remaining newlines replaced with spaces. This can all be done using a Python list comprehension as follows:

```
text = """Facebook and Google exploited a feature
intended for “enterprise developers” to
distribute apps that collect large amounts
of data on private users, TechCrunch first reported.

Apple’s maneuver has been characterized by some as a chilling demonstration of the company’s power.
Verge editor-in-chief Nilay Patel suggested in a tweet that it was cause for concern: First, they came for our enterprise certificates, then… well, what, exactly?"""

content = [block.replace('\n', ' ') for block in text.split('\n\n')]

print(content)
```

Giving you a list with two entries and no newlines:

```
['Facebook and Google exploited a feature intended for “enterprise developers” to distribute apps that collect large amounts of data on private users, TechCrunch first reported.', 'Apple’s maneuver has been characterized by some as a chilling demonstration of the company’s power. Verge editor-in-chief Nilay Patel suggested in a tweet that it was cause for concern: First, they came for our enterprise certificates, then… well, what, exactly?']
```

---

A regular expression could be used for the case where blocks are separated by two or more blank lines as follows:

```
import re

text = """Facebook and Google exploited a feature
intended for “enterprise developers” to
distribute apps that collect large amounts
of data on private users, TechCrunch first reported.



Apple’s maneuver has been characterized by some as a chilling demonstration of the company’s power.
Verge editor-in-chief Nilay Patel suggested in a tweet that it was cause for concern: First, they came for our enterprise certificates, then… well, what, exactly?"""

content = [block.replace('\n', ' ') for block in re.split('\n{2,}', text)]

print(content)
```

Comment: Martin, I used code. Well done. I wonder can we make it with regular expression. Which is better?

Comment: A regular expression version would be useful if your text sometimes contains more than two newlines rather than exactly two newlines to separate the blocks. I tend to prefer a non regular expression solution where possible.